# <Terminated> Eclipse. Cant Run my program

Tags: java, eclipse

I can't run my program and I don't know why. I'm new at programming and I have searched on all internet trying to fix this problem. It happens to me in 2 programs that I have, that are in different projects. I've tried to uninstall and install but it doesn't work. I'm using JRE 11 because it's what I'm learning in school.

1:

```
package estructurasRepetitivas;

public class Ejercicio3 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0;
    do {
      i += 5;
    } while (i <= 100);
  }
}
```

2:

```
package ejerciciosEstructurasAlternativas;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class EcuaciónSegundoGrado9 {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    double a = s.nextDouble();
    double b = s.nextDouble();
    double c = s.nextDouble();
    double xpositiva = (-b + Math.sqrt((b*b)-(4*a*c)))/(2*a);
    double xnegativa = (-b - Math.sqrt((b*b)-(4*a*c)))/(2*a);
    
    System.out.println("El resultado de la ecuación es: "+xpositiva);
    System.out.println("El resultado de la ecuación también es: "+xnegativa);
  }
}
```

It happened to me again:
3:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ejercicio7 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        //Declaramos Variables
        int combinacion = 1415;
        int intentos= s.nextInt() ;
        
        while (intentos != combinacion) {
            System.out.println("Lo siento, esa no es la combinación.");
            intentos = s.nextInt();
            
        } 
    }

}
```

Comment: `<Terminated>` in the header of the _Console_ view means that the program has been run successfully and has reached its end. Or what do you exactly mean by "I can't run my program"?

Comment: It doesn't show on the console the program. It just says <terminated>

Comment: It looks like its running but doesnt show nothing and it should for sure

Comment: The first program does not output anything so just showing Terminated is correct. Are you sure you are running the correct program?

Comment: Yea im running the correct program but sometimes i dont know why eclipse doesnt run some programs :C